# Plotting rectangle with the color column Matplotlib Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, plotly

I was trying to draw the color of the candles of OHLC. That was accomplished using the code available at:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51417197/4948889

But there is issue while I am trying it in my code. I will let know what situation is here.

```
dataset_train = pd.read_csv('EURUSD_M1TechnicalIndicators.csv',usecols=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])
dataset_train.head(10)
dataset_test = pd.read_csv('Test_EURUSD_M1TechnicalIndicators.csv',usecols=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15],nrows=50)
dataset_test.head(10)

train  = dataset_train.filter(['open','high','low','close','closeTarget',"k","d","atr","macdmain","macdsgnal","bbup","bbmid","bblow"], axis=1)
x = train.values #returns a numpy array
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
datasetTrain = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled)
datasetTrain.columns = ['open','high','low','close','closeTarget',"k","d","atr","macdmain","macdsgnal","bbup","bbmid","bblow"]
datasetTrain.head(10) 

test = dataset_test.filter(['open','high','low','close','closeTarget',"k","d","atr","macdmain","macdsgnal","bbup","bbmid","bblow"], axis=1)
x = test.values #returns a numpy array
min_max_scaler = preprocessing.MinMaxScaler()
x_scaled = min_max_scaler.fit_transform(x)
datasetTest = pd.DataFrame(x_scaled)
datasetTest.columns = ['open','high','low','close','closeTarget',"k","d","atr","macdmain","macdsgnal","bbup","bbmid","bblow"]
datasetTest.head(10)

plt.figure(figsize=(25,5))
plt.plot(xTrain[:,3])
plt.title('Train (' +str(len(xTrain))+' data points)')
plt.show()
plt.figure(figsize=(10,3))
plt.plot(xTest[:,0])
plt.title('Test (' +str(len(xTest))+' data points)')
plt.show()
```

The output till here was:

[image: train]

[image: test]

Then I tried this:

```
def draw_rects(ax, quotes, width=5., height=1., yloc=1., colorup='g', 
               colordown='r', edgecolor='k', alpha=1.0):

    OFFSET = width / 2.0
    patches = []
    for q in quotes:
        t, open, close, high, low = q[:5]
        if close > open:
            color = colorup
        else:
            color = colordown

        rect = Rectangle(
            xy=(t - OFFSET, yloc),
            width=width,
            height=height,
            facecolor=color,
            edgecolor=edgecolor,
        )
        rect.set_alpha(alpha)
        patches.append(rect)
        ax.add_patch(rect)

    ax.autoscale_view()

    return patches

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
quotes = xTest
p1 = draw_rects(ax, xTrain, yloc=1)
p2 = draw_rects(ax, xTest, yloc=4)
labels = [item.get_text() for item in ax.get_yticklabels()]
labels[2] = 'Train'
labels[8] = 'Test'
ax.set_yticklabels(labels)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image: outptu]

I was expecting the candles color to be shown. So that above process didn't worked for me. So I created another column in the `dataset` as color and `shiftedcolor`

Now I am thinking to just showcase the color data from the datasets in the candle fashion using the rectangles. Please help me in doing that.

Here are the datasets used by me. [EURUSD_M1TechnicalIndicators And Test_EURUSD_M1TechnicalIndicators](https://github.com/JafferWilson/datasets)

Comment: By looking at the plot now knowing that your Files have 30202 lines - couldn't this plot be ok but just hard to read because of thousands of (possibly overlapping) rectangles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really get the complexity of your problem plotting some rectangles (no offending, please correct me if I just ignored important things, in other words: tl;dr...)

But just as an example, how I would plot those two rows (let's say as a different approach to start discussing if it's worth it...):

```
x = np.arange(10)
y = np.ones(10)

bools = np.random.randint(0, 2, 10).astype(bool)
colors = np.array(bools, str)
colors[bools] = 'g'
colors[~bools] = 'r'

rx = 1
ry = 2
rect = [(-rx, -ry), (rx, -ry), (rx, ry), (-rx, ry)]

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(x, y, facecolor=colors, verts=rect, s=1000)
plt.scatter(x, y+3, facecolor=colors[::-1], verts=rect, s=1000)
plt.ylim(0, 5)
plt.yticks([1, 4], ['Train', 'Test'])
```

leads to:

[image]

**EDIT:**
The same thing applied to your data files:
(And I saw you want also black for equal values, so added this, too)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dataset_train = pd.read_csv('EURUSD_M1TechnicalIndicators.txt', usecols=['open', 'close'])
dataset_test = pd.read_csv('Test_EURUSD_M1TechnicalIndicators.csv', usecols=['open', 'close'])

gt_train = (dataset_train.open - dataset_train.close) > 0
gt_test = (dataset_test.open - dataset_test.close) > 0
eq_train = (dataset_train.open - dataset_train.close) == 0
eq_test = (dataset_test.open - dataset_test.close) == 0

y_train = np.ones(len(gt_train))
y_test = np.ones(len(gt_test))

colors_train = np.array(gt_train, str)
colors_test = np.array(gt_test, str)
colors_train[gt_train] = 'g'
colors_train[~gt_train] = 'r'
colors_train[eq_train] = 'k'
colors_test[gt_test] = 'g'
colors_test[~gt_test] = 'r'
colors_test[eq_test] = 'k'

rx = .2
ry = 2
rect = [(-rx, -ry), (rx, -ry), (rx, ry), (-rx, ry)]

plt.figure()
plt.scatter(np.arange(y_train.size), y_train, facecolor=colors_train, verts=rect, s=1000)
plt.scatter(np.arange(y_test.size), y_test+3, facecolor=colors_test, verts=rect, s=1000)
plt.ylim(0, 5)
plt.yticks([1, 4], ['Train', 'Test'])
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, this one is what an excellent answer I have got till now. Can you just help me get them labelled please?

Comment: Which labels please? You can set 'x = np.arange(-2, 4)' if you like to get the x tick labels you posted above. Or 'plt.yticks([1, 4], ['Train', 'Test'])' for your y axis labels. Or did you want to label the markers themselves?

Comment: It was obviously the axis label what I mean. I guess is done. One more thing, Can you tell me if I wanted to increase the gap between the two rectangles then what I have to do?

Comment: You can change the aspect ratio of the rectangle which is defined in the `verts` kwarg. I added two parameters `rx`and `ry`, so that you can easily adjust it.

Comment: Thank you sir for your help. I am checking it out.

Comment: Sir can you just please modify the second example what you have suggested to look like the output that you have mentioned in the first example. Something separated. I am getting the damn messy output and is not understandable. Please can you just help me do that. I tried to modify the values of `rx` and `ry` to 1 and 2 but there is nothing happening. Please help me.

Comment: You don't see gaps in the second plot because there are thousands of rectangles plotted on your ~80dpi-screen... Try to zoom in until you have the range of some few samples on the x axis. There the plot will look like the first again.