# How to plot candlesticks

Tags: python, plot, finance, candlestick-chart

I´m trying to create a simple plot with candlesticks. For that I get the data from Yahoo and plot it using the function candlestick2_ohlc. The goal is to export the image in a jpg file using.

This is the code what I´m using:

```
from pandas_datareader import data
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_finance import candlestick2_ohlc
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import fix_yahoo_finance as yf
import datetime

start = datetime.date(2018, 1, 1)
end = datetime.date.today()
    
aapl = yf.download("AAPL",start,end) 
aapl.reset_index(inplace=True)

aapl['Date'] = aapl.index.map(mdates.date2num)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.xlabel("Date")
plt.ylabel("Price")

candlestick2_ohlc(ax, aapl.Open, aapl.High, aapl.Low, aapl.Close, width=1, colorup='g')
plt.savefig('my_figure.png')
plt.show()
```

My first question is: there is another simple way to do it? Could you please give me an example to work with finance data? I usually work with quantmod in R.

The second question is: In my example, there is no Date in the X axis. What can I do to show the plot with Dates in the X axis? I should transform the Date into a AX format but I don't know a simple way to do it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to plot ohlc candlestick with datetime in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36334665/how-to-plot-ohlc-candlestick-with-datetime-in-matplotlib)

Comment: No, in my case I´m using Dates, no Intraday and I´m asking more thinks. thanks :)

Comment: I don't believe it matters the frequency, yours and dup question involves datetimes. Also what does *simple way to do it* mean? You have one plot line and 4-5 `plt` settings (typical of matplotlib solutions).

Answer (score 18):

There are many ways of how plotting candlesticks in python using different package like:

1. mplfinance
2. plotly
3. finplot
4. etc.

You can also create your own specialized version of candlesticks using `matplotlib` package.

### mplfinance Package

You can install the package using the following command:

```
pip install mplfinance
```

Then, you should use it as the following:

1. Indices should be from `DatetimeIndex` format.
2. The dataset should have the columns named: `High`, `Open`, `Close` and `Low`. (it's case-sensitive)
3. (optional) if you want to show the volume, the `Volume` named column is required.

**PS 1:** You can create DatetimeIndex using pandas `to_datetime` method.
**PS 2:** You can rename a column using `rename` method on dataframe.

**Sample:**

```
import pandas as pd
import mplfinance as mpf

df = pd.read_csv("<dataframe-path>", index_col=0)
mpf.plot(df, type='candle', style='yahoo', volume=True)
```

### plotly Package

First you need to install the `plotly` package using:

```
pip install plotly
```

Then, you can plot the candle plots as easy as the following code:

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_csv('your_file_address')

fig = go.Figure(data=[go.Candlestick(x=df['name_of_time_column'],
                open=df['name_of_open_column'],
                high=df['name_of_high_column'],
                low=df['name_of_low_column'],
                close=df['name_of_close_column'])])

fig.show()
```

### finplot Package

You can install finplot package using the following command:

```
pip install finplot
```

then, it's really easy to build a candlestick plot.

**Example:**

```
import finplot as fplt
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("<data-path.csv>")

fplt.candlestick_ochl(df[['Open', 'Close', 'High', 'Low']])
fplt.show()
```

Answer (score 8):

[finplot](https://pypi.org/project/finplot/) has working dates:

```
import finplot as fplt
import yfinance
df = yfinance.download('AAPL')
fplt.candlestick_ochl(df[['Open', 'Close', 'High', 'Low']])
fplt.show()
```

[image: finplot shows your dates]

Not only does it show your dates, but also has many improvements (too many to list here).

**Disclaimer:** I dislike matplotlib's and plotly's API's (and performance and lack of functionality), so created finplot. Already it has 9% of the mpl_finance's pypi stars, so check it!

Comment: I have just updated (my answer)[https://stackoverflow.com/a/59256790/7310077], it would be  a nice experience to try. I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks @MostafaGhadimi! I try to emphasize ease of use and performance, which is why I made it in the first place.

Comment: Yeah. Thank you very much, Jonas. Yeah you're right, my upvote goes for you man. It is a really good answer.

Comment: Hi @JonasByström! I just installed finplot, and tried your example (litteraly copied your code). I get the following error: [IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4]. Did you ever encoutered this one?

Comment: @the_drug Nope, sounds strange. Did you try any of the dozen included examples? Open an issue on [github](https://github.com/highfestiva/finplot/issues) if the problem remains.

Comment: @JonasByström i also like your library. from the first glimpse i got it seems to be easy and straight forward to use :)
maybe you could write some kind of documentation for the 'clean API' you mention in your readmes. Guess that would make it a) a bit more professional and b) lower the entry hurdle.

thanks for your work so far :)
I'll start using it today and see how far I'll get ;)

Comment: @3.141592 I use examples instead of documentation. The reason is that's how I personally prefer to learn. Good luck though!

Comment: @the_drug i got the same error, but here is the fix -- example should actually be fplt.candlestick_ochl(df[['Timestamp', 'Open', 'Close', 'High', 'Low']])

Comment: @OlDor could your `yfinance` module be older than 3 years? Before [this](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance/commit/a1dfc6f1215b25bed4fb3444d0f58bb308f02188) fix possibly?

Comment: @JonasByström i didn't use yfinance, i have my own data_df

Comment: @OlDor the_drug said he "litteraly copied [the] code." Sounds like you both exaggerated on either the "litteraly" or the "copied" part. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Use Plotly and you can plot a candlestick chart with one line of code.

```
df[['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']]['2018-01-01':'20XX-XX-XX'].iplot(kind="candle")
```

Before using plotly, you need install plotly and cufflinks with `pip` at your command line:

```
pip install plotly

pip install cufflinks
```

Also you need to import followings on the top of your Jupiter Notebook:

```
from plotly import __version__

import cufflinks as cf

from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs, init_notebook_mode, plot, iplot

init_notebook_mode (connected=True)

cf.go_offline()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do everthing with matplot (use Boxplot)

```
df = pdr.data.get_data_yahoo(ticker, start='2012-01-01', end='2012-10-10')
df = df[['Open', 'High', 'Low', 'Close']]

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(figsize=(14,7), num='figure name')

ax1.set_title('box title')
ax1.yaxis.grid(True, linestyle='-', which='major', color='lightgrey', alpha=0.5)
ax1.xaxis.grid(True, linestyle='-', which='major', color='lightgrey', alpha=0.5)

bp = ax1.boxplot(df, patch_artist=True, labels=df.index.astype(str))

# green up, red down
for count_box in range(len(df.index)):
    if (df.iloc[count_box,0]-df.iloc[count_box,3])>=0:
       plt.setp(bp['boxes'][count_box], color='red')
    else:
       plt.setp(bp['boxes'][count_box], color='green')

 plt.xticks(rotation=30)
 plt.show() #or plt.savefig()
```

Comment: Getting the error:    plt.setp(bp['boxes'][count_box], color='green')

IndexError: list index out of range