# Plot OLHCV from Pandas DataFrame with Color Candles & Volume as Horizontal Lines

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib, candlestick-chart

I have a Dataframe Like Below:

```
        Symbol            DateTime      open      high       low     close   volume
0    BANKNIFTY 2019-09-09 09:15:00  27266.20  27266.20  27063.20  27115.00  19200.0
1    BANKNIFTY 2019-09-09 09:16:00  27112.85  27118.90  27096.10  27101.95   6820.0
2    BANKNIFTY 2019-09-09 09:17:00  27105.00  27142.35  27105.00  27135.95      0.0
3    BANKNIFTY 2019-09-09 09:18:00  27130.55  27140.00  27106.95  27113.00  12560.0
4    BANKNIFTY 2019-09-09 09:19:00  27113.55  27113.55  27077.00  27090.55      0.0
5    BANKNIFTY 2019-09-09 09:20:00  27083.05  27083.05  27039.15  27071.85  21260.0
6    BANKNIFTY 2019-09-09 09:21:00  27079.00  27099.00  27070.55  27080.00   2720.0
7    BANKNIFTY 2019-09-09 09:22:00  27082.45  27091.60  27071.05  27088.65      0.0
8    BANKNIFTY 2019-09-09 09:23:00  27086.65  27099.40  27081.20  27088.70      0.0
9    BANKNIFTY 2019-09-09 09:24:00  27085.45  27094.00  27079.95  27084.90      0.0
10   BANKNIFTY 2019-09-09 09:25:00  27084.90  27084.90  27070.00  27074.85      0.0
11   BANKNIFTY 2019-09-09 09:26:00  27074.85  27080.00  27070.00  27074.00      0.0
12   BANKNIFTY 2019-09-09 09:27:00  27073.05  27075.00  27065.70  27066.05      0.0
13   BANKNIFTY 2019-09-09 09:28:00  27066.05  27086.65  27062.00  27084.90      0.0
14   BANKNIFTY 2019-09-09 09:29:00  27085.45  27108.80  27080.05  27101.25      0.0
15   BANKNIFTY 2019-09-09 09:30:00  27100.00  27100.85  27076.00  27079.50   2900.0
16   BANKNIFTY 2019-09-09 09:31:00  27079.00  27114.00  27079.00  27113.95   3900.0
17   BANKNIFTY 2019-09-09 09:32:00  27110.00  27118.95  27102.70  27103.30      0.0
```

I want to plot the data in OLHCV using matplotlib with below conditions:

> 1. Where Close > Open then Candle Color = Green
> 2. Where Close < Open then Candle Color = Red
> 3. Where Volume is Non-Zero then Candle Color = Blue
> 4. Plot Volume Candle (only for non Zero Volume values) as Horizontal Lines from Right side upto the Current Candle **Close Value** with **Volume Value** written on top of the line.

Any Help...

Sample Output will be like:
[image: Output]

Comment: Please try working on it yourself first, and then posting a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if you encounter problems.

Comment: Sir, I am new to matplotlib and able to plot candles with red and green color as of date. I will be grateful if you can help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to plot ohlc candlestick with datetime in matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36334665/how-to-plot-ohlc-candlestick-with-datetime-in-matplotlib)

Comment: No Sir, my requirements are different.