# hidden axis in a matplotlib plot is visible after loading back the file

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, matplotlib, tensorflow2.0

I used the code from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36334665/how-to-plot-ohlc-candlestick-with-datetime-in-matplotlib) to generate candle-stick charts on stock prices. The code hides the axis and everything is just fine.

```py
        plt.figure()
        width = 1
        width2 = 0.1
        pricesup = df[df.close >= df.open]
        pricesdown = df[df.close < df.open]

        plt.bar(pricesup.index, pricesup.close - pricesup.open, width, bottom=pricesup.open, color='g')
        plt.bar(pricesup.index, pricesup.high - pricesup.close, width2, bottom=pricesup.close, color='g')
        plt.bar(pricesup.index, pricesup.low - pricesup.open, width2, bottom=pricesup.open, color='g')

        plt.bar(pricesdown.index, pricesdown.close - pricesdown.open, width, bottom=pricesdown.open, color='r')
        plt.bar(pricesdown.index, pricesdown.high - pricesdown.open, width2, bottom=pricesdown.open, color='r')
        plt.bar(pricesdown.index, pricesdown.low - pricesdown.close, width2, bottom=pricesdown.close, color='r')

        plt.gca().set_axis_off()
        plt.subplots_adjust(
            top=1,
            bottom=0,
            right=1,
            left=0,
            hspace=0,
            wspace=0
        )
        plt.margins(0, 0)
        plt.savefig(file_path, bbox_inches='tight', format=file_format, dpi=72)
```

But when I load the image using TensorFlow decode_png method, it shows the hidden axis:

```py
image = tf.io.read_file('test.png')
image = tf.io.decode_png(image)
plt.imshow(image)
plt.show()
```

Image loaded through windows Photo:
[image: image loaded through Windows Photo]

Image loaded in Pythin with TensorFlow library:

[image: Image loaded in Pythin with TensorFlow library]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not showing the hidden axis, your image is properly saved without the first axis. But `plt.imshow()` is creating and showing a new axis when you open the image. Add the line `plt.axis('off')` after `plt.imshow(image)` and it should remove this new axis.

Comment: Thank you! So it's a completely made-up x-y axis?

Comment: @MehdiZare No problem! I think it counts the pixels in the image, I tried it and the axes match the image size